# How to get newest reply of a user in discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to write a discord bot to get some information from user when they reply my bot on channel. 
So when they

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        await message.channel.send('Say hello!')
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        print(message.content)
```

When I run the code and message  *$greet* to my bot, it will reply with *Say hello!*, when I message *hello*, it responds with *$greet*, but I want it to reply *hello*

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the object `message.content` is the original commmand used, which in this case is `$greet`. You should rather compare the `msg` object instead,

```
await ctx.send(msg.content)
```

You can get the message content and its author by:

```
msg, user = client.wait_for(*args)
```

You can read more about `wait_for` [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

This is a really basic error and I would recommend learning a but more of python before making a discord bot

Comment: Sorry because i answer a simple question. I solve it. Thank so much

Comment: Great! Theres no issue with asking simple questions though! You should feel free to ask for whatever help you need, as long as you have tried fixing the error or done some reasearch first.

Comment: `wait_for('message')` returns a `Message` object, not a tuple.  You can check the [event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-api-events) to see what each event returns, because the listener for that event will take those values as its arguments.

Comment: Whoops! My bad! Sorry @DarkFawkes , I've made the necassery edits

Comment: Follow your answer. I dont it, well. I call print('New reply is {0.content}'.format(msg)) and it work